# Are $(0,1) \times [0,1)$ and $[0,1) \times [0,1)$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, product-space

I do not know how to approach. I tried removing points and see if the remaining spaces are connected or not, but i couldn't conclude anything without doubt.

Comment: The discussion in wikipedia might be a direction to consider:  "The one-dimensional intervals [ 0 , 1 ] and ( 0 , 1 ) are not homeomorphic because no continuous bijection could be made.[4]"  See under "non-examples" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like it should be.  Imagine a pizza crust on a square tray with two adjacent closed edges.  You can twist and stretch that around to move the closed edges to just being on one side.  I don't know if it would be pleasant to describe it mathematically, but there's your homeomorphism.

Comment: They are both homeomorphic to half of the open unit disc, with diameter included.

Comment: Almost the same: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3229483/are-the-topological-spaces-0-1-times-0-1-and-0-1-times-0-1-homeomorp

Comment: Wlog the question is : $\Bbb{H}^2 \approx [0.\infty) \times [0,\infty)$ ? where $\Bbb{H}^2:= \Bbb{R}\times [0,\infty)$.This question and its generalization already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855110/are-the-spaces-mathbbhn-and-overline-mathbbrn-homeomorphic?noredirect=1&lq=1). With $n=2$, try the rotation map $z \mapsto z^2$ as in complex analysis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are the spaces $\mathbb{H}^n$ and $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^n_+$ homeomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855110/are-the-spaces-mathbbhn-and-overline-mathbbrn-homeomorphic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try rotating and stretching $[0,1)^2$ to $(-1,1)\times [0,1)$ in the sense that points on the $x$-axis remain in place, points on the $y = x$ line rotate to points on the $y$-axis, and points on the $y$-axis rotate to points on the negative $x$-axis. More formally, a point with polar angle $\phi \in \left[0, \frac\pi2\right]$ will rotate to a point with polar angle $2\phi$.

We also have to scale the distances of points from the origin. Introduce the following continuous function $L : [0,2\pi] \to [1,\sqrt{2}]$ as
$$L(\phi) := \begin{cases} \frac1{\left|\cos\phi\right|}, &\text{if }\phi \in \left[0, \frac\pi4\right] \cup \left[\frac{3\pi}4,2\pi\right]\\
\frac1{\sin\phi}, &\text{if }\phi \in \left[\frac\pi4, \frac{3\pi}4\right]
\end{cases}$$
which measures the width of $(-1,1)\times [0,1)$ along the line with polar angle $\phi$.

Now check that $f : [0,1)^2 \to (-1,1)\times [0,1)$ given in polar coordinates by $f(0,0) = (0,0)$ and
$$r(\cos\phi, \sin\phi) \mapsto r(\cos2\phi, \sin2\phi)\frac{L(2\phi)}{L(\phi)}\quad \text{ for } r > 0, \phi\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$$
is a homeomorphism with inverse 
$$(0,0) \mapsto (0,0)$$
$$r(\cos\phi, \sin\phi) \mapsto r\left(\cos\frac12\phi, \sin\frac12\phi\right)\frac{L\left(\frac12\phi\right)}{L(\phi)}\quad \text{ for } r > 0, \phi\in[0,2\pi]$$

Finally, notice that $g : (-1,1) \times [0,1) \to (0,1) \times [0,1)$ given by $g(x,y) = \left(\frac{1+x}2, y\right)$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

Here's anther recipe for finding an explicit homeomorphism $\ f:[0,1)\times[0,1)\rightarrow (0,1)\times[0,1)\ $. On the blue region of the first figure below, on and above the line $\ x+y=1\ $, choose 
$\ f\ $ to be the identity.  In the region below that line choose $\ f\ $ to map the green lines (of slope $1$) in the first diagram onto the vertical green lines in the second.

[image]

Comment: I believe that's $[0,1)\times (0,1)$ on the second picture, but otherwise it looks good.

Comment: Yes, of course you're right. I've now updated the diagram.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the open unit disk together with an arc of finite length from its bounding unit circle.

I think it's clear that any two such sets are homeomorphic,  independent of the length of the arc.

For the sets in question, which are squares, project (stretch) each homeomorphically from its center to the circumscribing disk. The result is two sets as above, one with a fourth and one with a half the circumference.